# The convexity of $\frac{|x|}{1+|x|}$

Tags: convex-analysis

Let $f(x)=\frac{|x|}{1+|x|}$, the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$. Clearly, $f$ is even, and is nondecreasing in $[0,\infty)$ and is nonincresing in $(-\infty,0)$. It seems that $f(x)$ is convex, but I don't know how to prove it by definition. I also tried to prove convexity using convexity preserving operations, but failed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "It seems that $f(x)$ is convex": [not at all](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+%5Cfrac%7B%7Cx%7C%7D%7B1%2B%7Cx%7C%7D).

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function  is $C^2$ for $x \ne 0$, so you can analyze convexity separately in $]-\infty,0[$ and $]0, +\infty[$ just by studying the sign of the second derivative.The function is not convex or concave in intervals that contain $x=0$.

Comment: Indeed, a graph reveals the non convexity clearly: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ruu5.png

Comment: Indeed (same prior comment above), so I think the post did not show enough effort to deserve an answer.